# Meaning of group generated by two sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that the group generated by a subset $A$ is the smallest group that contains $A$. I also know that we say that a group $G$ is generated by a set $A\subset G$ if every element if $g\in G$ can be written as
$$g = \sum_{i=1}^ra_i\lambda_i$$
where $a_j\in A \: \forall j = 1,\ldots,r$ and $\lambda_j \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now I am wondering how a group generated by two sets/groups looks like. I know it must be the smallest group containing both sets, but I would like to get an expression like the above for the elements in the large group in terms of the elements of the small ones. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much the same as your example. Suppose that $A_1,A_2 \subset G$.
Then the subgroup generated by $A_1,A_2$ consists of expressions of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i,$$ with $a_i \in A_1$ or $a_i \in A_2$.
Setting $A := A_1 \cup A_2$, you can see how this case is pretty much the same as the one you already understand.

Comment: In that case, there must be elements like $\lambda_i a_i + \mu_i b_i$ where $a_i \in A_i$ and $b_i \in A_2$, right?

Comment: @kubo edit: elements such as $a+b$ for $a\in A_1, b\in A_2$ are in there, simply let $a_1=a, a_2=b, a_i = 0$ for $i>2$, and $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$.